# Cannot activate local server NODE-RED

Tags: node-red, opc-ua, node-opcua

[image]

Hi everyone, I have a question about NODE-RED. When I call node-red on cmd, all palletes and server are loaded, besides there are some warnings and errors like a picture and I cannot access to the server. Can someone help me to solve this problem because I have approached NODE-RED for a short time. Thank you!

Before I have solved problem about credentialsecret but it does not work

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are hard to read, impossible for people that use screen readers and unsearchable. Please post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to raise this with the owner of the `node-red-contrib-opcua` node as it needs to validate all input and to catch all the exceptions that could be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The error basically says it: "data"."act_tss" is not a valid string.

Try "data.act_tss" instead.